# Last order timestamp per product

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find the **last payment** (or `NULL` if n/a) made for which specified `product_id`. Below is a representation of the tables I'm working with (simplified version).

```
+----------+
|Products  |
|----------+
|product_id|
+----------+
+---------------+
|Orders         |
+---------------+
|order_id       |
|order_timestamp|
|order_status   |
+---------------+
+-----------------+
|ProductsOrdersMap|
+-----------------+
|product_id       |
|order_id         |
+-----------------+
```

After JOINs, MAXs, GROUP BYs, LEFT JOINs, multiple INNER JOINs to get the greatest-n-per-group, I still can't get to the right result. Most of the times, products with multiple orders are returning multiple rows. The best results I got so far were (I was searching specific products):

```
product_id  order_id  order_timestamp      order_status
8           NULL      NULL                 NULL
9           NULL      NULL                 NULL
10          NULL      NULL                 NULL
12          NULL      NULL                 NULL
13          NULL      NULL                 NULL
14          11        2013-08-13 07:22:01  finished
15          11        2013-08-13 07:22:01  finished
15          12        2013-08-14 00:00:00  finished
32          11        2013-08-13 07:22:01  finished
83          9         2013-08-13 07:04:02  finished
83          10        2013-08-13 07:11:42  finished
```

**Edit:** After PP. anwser, I ended up with the following query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, o.order_id, MAX(order_timestamp) AS order_timestamp, order_status
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN (ProductsOrdersMap m, Orders o)
  ON (p.product_id = m.product_id AND m.order_id = o.order_id)
WHERE p.product_id IN (8,9,10,12,13,14,15,32,83)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Which returns

```
product_id  order_id  order_timestamp      order_status
8           NULL      NULL                 NULL
9           NULL      NULL                 NULL
10          NULL      NULL                 NULL
12          NULL      NULL                 NULL
13          NULL      NULL                 NULL
14          11        2013-08-13 07:22:01  finished
15          11        2013-08-13 07:22:01  finished
32          11        2013-08-13 07:22:01  finished
83          9         2013-08-13 07:04:02  finished
```

At first glance, it seems correct but only the products IDs and the timestamps are right. Comparing the two queries above, you can see that, for products 15 and 83, `order_id` is wrong (`order_status` might be wrong as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return the specified resultset (this is only desk checked, not tested)

**to return ALL product_id**

```
SELECT p.product_id
     , m.order_d
     , m.order_timestamp
     , m.order_status
  FROM products p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT kl.product_id
              , MAX(ko.order_timestamp) AS latest_timestamp
           FROM orderproductsmap kl
           JOIN orders ko
             ON ko.order_id = kl.order_id
          GROUP
             BY kl.product_id
       ) l
    ON l.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ml.product_id
              , mo.order_id
              , mo.order_timestamp
              , mo.order_status
           FROM orderproductsmap ml
           JOIN orders mo
             ON mo.order_id = ml.order_id
       ) m
    ON m.product_id = l.product_id
   AND m.order_timestamp = l.latest_timestamp
 GROUP
    BY p.product_id
```

The inline view "`l`" gets us the latest "`order_timestamp`" for each "`product_id`". This is joined to inline view "`m`" to get us the whole row for the order that has the latest timestamp.

If there happens to be more than one order with the same latest "`order_timestamp`" (i.e. `order_timestamp` is not guaranteed to be unique for a given `product_id`) then the outermost `GROUP BY` ensures that only one of those order rows is returned.

If only particular product_id values need to be returned, add a WHERE clause in the outermost query. For performance, that same predicate can be repeated in the inline views.

**to return only SPECIFIC product_id** we add three WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT p.product_id
     , m.order_d
     , m.order_timestamp
     , m.order_status
  FROM products p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT kl.product_id
              , MAX(ko.order_timestamp) AS latest_timestamp
           FROM orderproductsmap kl
           JOIN orders ko
             ON ko.order_id = kl.order_id
          WHERE kl.product_id IN (8,9,10,12,13,14,15,32,83)
          GROUP
             BY kl.product_id
       ) l
    ON l.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ml.product_id
              , mo.order_id
              , mo.order_timestamp
              , mo.order_status
           FROM orderproductsmap ml
           JOIN orders mo
             ON mo.order_id = ml.order_id
          WHERE ml.product_id IN (8,9,10,12,13,14,15,32,83)
       ) m
    ON m.product_id = l.product_id
   AND m.order_timestamp = l.latest_timestamp
 WHERE p.product_id IN (8,9,10,12,13,14,15,32,83)
 GROUP
    BY p.product_id
```

Only the WHERE clause on the outermost query is required. The other two are added just to improve performance by limiting the size of each of the derived tables.

Comment: I tested the first query and it works! But it should be `SELECT p.product_id` instead of `SELECT k.product_id`.

Comment: Good catch, yes, that should be "`p.`" not "`k.`"

Comment: Thank you for the second query, plus the optimization warning. I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT
        P.product_id
        ,MAX(order_timestamp)
    FROM
        Products P
        ,Orders O
        ,ProductsOrdersMap M
    WHERE
        P.product_id = M.product_id
        AND O.order_id = M.order_id
    GROUP BY
        P.product_id
```

Comment: It looks like that code worked o.o and not a single join... I was overthinking, I guess.

Comment: How to return all the products, even the ones without orders? With `LEFT JOIN` I'd know but with this way, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

To return all products, even those without orders, a `LEFT JOIN` is definitely the way to go. The answer from @PP above uses "old-style" inner joins and is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT
    P.product_id
    ,MAX(order_timestamp)
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN ProductsOrdersMap M ON P.product_id = M.product_id
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.order_id = M.order_id
GROUP BY
    P.product_id
```

Starting with this syntax it's a lot easier to get to the `LEFT JOIN` - just replace `INNER` with `LEFT`:

```
SELECT
    P.product_id
    ,MAX(order_timestamp)
FROM Products P
LEFT JOIN ProductsOrdersMap M ON P.product_id = M.product_id
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON O.order_id = M.order_id
GROUP BY
    P.product_id
```

---

**Addendum**: Renato needed something more than just reworking the other answer as a `LEFT JOIN` because the `order_id` and `order_status` have to come along with the maximum timestamp. The easiest approach is to start with a list of product ID's and order ID's where the order has the maximum timestamp by `order_id`:

```
SELECT
  p2.product_id,
  o2.order_id
FROM Products p2
INNER JOIN ProductsOrdersMap m ON p2.product_id = m.product_id
INNER JOIN Orders o2 ON m.order_id = o2.order_id
WHERE (o2.order_id, o2.order_timestamp) IN (
  SELECT order_id, MAX(order_timestamp)
  FROM Orders
  GROUP BY order_id)
```

Then, instead of using `ProductsOrdersMap` to resolve products to orders, use the results from the query above:

```
SELECT
  p.product_id,
  o.order_id,
  o.TS,
  o.order_status
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    p2.product_id,
    o2.order_id
  FROM Products p2
  INNER JOIN ProductsOrdersMap m ON p2.product_id = m.product_id
  INNER JOIN Orders o2 ON m.order_id = o2.order_id
  WHERE (o2.order_id, o2.order_timestamp) IN (
    SELECT order_id, MAX(order_timestamp)
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY order_id)
  ) MaxTS ON p.product_id = MaxTS.product_id
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON MaxTS.order_id = o.order_id
```

Comment: Check my question after edit. I got to the same result as you, yet it's returning wrong values.

Comment: OK, I think I know what you're after. All I did above was change the other answer into LEFT JOINS, and I can see from your edit that that's not quite enough to get the results you want. I'll post an update shortly and let you know when it's ready.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing before your answer (my edit) :D And yet, I failed miserably... Thank you.

Comment: Renato - I've updated my answer. Let me know if that's closer to what you want. It's tough to exclude rows when left joining, and I don't have MySQL access today so I can't test it out. If you do end up with extra rows due to the left join to `ProductsOrderMap` we can fold that table into the subquery as well.

Comment: Ed Gibbs - I suppose that with `MaxTS.TS` you meant `MaxTS.order_timestamp`. And it's how you feared: I ended up with duplicate rows.

Comment: I've put up another attempt; if that doesn't do the job could you check the newer answer? If the newer answer doesn't work out and you want to pursue this with me could you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with tables and the data for the products in your desired results? I know this can be done, but without sample data I can't check my results, and I don't want to keep throwing incorrect queries at you :)

Comment: Ed Gibbs, same duplicate rows :( I'm going to accept the other answer since it works. But, hey man, thank you very much for all your restless efforts.

Comment: You're welcome Renato, and I'm glad the other answer works for you :)